# Overpass Query to find ways of a route geometry

Tags: overpass-api

**Problem**

I have a *route geometry* in the format:

- OSM node-1 coordinates
- OSM node-2 coordinates
- OSM node-3 coordinates
- ...

And I need to know which *OSM ways* were "used" by the route.

**Question**

Is there an Overpass query which can return me the ways which are required to "form" the route geometry with one request?

- fyi: The geometries' route is always "connected" by shared way nodes.

e.g.:

- **input:** geometry = [**node102, node103, node104, node303, node304**]
- **output:** wayIds = [way1, way2, way3]
- where way1 is e.g. [node101, **node102, node103, node104**, node105]
- where way2 is e.g. [**node104, node303**]
- where way3 is e.g. [**node303, node304**, node305]

**Context**

I'm using a routing API which only returns the Geometry of the Route (OSM node coordinates) but no ids.

The problem is that I need to know which OSM ways were used to construct this route.

**What I've tried so far**

1. I can get all the node id from the node coordinates using `node(around:0,lat,lon)`
2. Thanks to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/244291/115854) I can get the ways which contain a set of nodes using

```
node(around:0,latNode1,lonNode1,latNode2,lonNode2)->.allnodes;

way(bn.allnodes)->.ways;

foreach .ways -> .singleway (
  node.allnodes(w.singleway);
  way.singleway(bn)(if:count(nodes) == allnodes.count(nodes));
  out geom;
);
```

3. Unfortunately I don't know how many nodes of a way were used by the route. Right now I only can think of:

   a. find all ways for node1, node2

   b. if more than one way found --> add another node to (a) and try again

   c. when I found the way, search the next way with the geometries next node pair which is not part of the way I just found (i.e. continue with (a))

   But this approach would require me to make many request to the Overpass API. I can't figure out how to write this logic as Overpass Query. I'm running my own overpass server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I picked was:

- map-match the route (again) with [Valhalla](https://valhalla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/map-matching/api-reference/#trace-attributes-action) Map-Matching mode `trace_attributes` and algorithm `shape_match:edge_walk`
- The `edge_walk` algorithm takes into account that the input route was already matched close to the OSM ways.
- **This mode returns the way ids** used by the matched route.
- With these wayIds I can query Overpass with one simple, fast query to get all the other way data for all ways: `way(id:1, 2, 3, 4, ...)`